# neo4j manual mapping POJO

Tags: xml, neo4j

can Ne04j map class name and members with manual names (like in jaxb)?

e.g:
( not sure about jaxb syntax but this is the idea.)

```
@XmlRoot(name="my_foo_class")
class Foo{
   @XmlNode(name="foo_id")
   int fId;
}
```

I want this to ba able rename more easily in the code implement different class versions and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neo4j has no in-built support for this. You need to use [Spring Data Neo4j](http://www.springsource.org/spring-data/neo4j) (SDN) for this feature. Below is how you would map Foo using SDN. Refactoring of the class names is possible without impacting the existing db using `@TypeAlias`. However, the property names can't be aliased right now.

```
@NodeEntity
@TypeAlias("F")
class Foo
{
   @GraphProperty
   int fId;
}
```

Comment: Thanks!! just one more thing. is the mapping done in an additional file like xml ? is that means that I will be have to modify it too?

Comment: @ozma No external mapping filw. It is all through annotations.